# How to auto start terminal applications when Fedora 14 starts?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-14

I know that i can go under system-> preferences -> startup to add in application that i want to autostart when fedora starts. But if my application requires to open terminal then type ./[appname] inorder to execute it, what should i type in the command field in the auto start section such that it will auto run at terminal upon os starts? thanks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728878/how-to-make-my-application-auto-start-after-system-bootup-rpm-fedora-10

Comment: deleted =))))))

Comment: Warren P: how can i create the .desktop file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://opensource.osu.edu/node/227) and [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Oracle-9i-Fedora-3-Install-HOWTO/sect_08.html), the procedure to run a script on boot for Fedora is as follows:

1: Create a bash script to do what you want, in form of

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 345 91 19
# description: Script to do what I want.

OWNER="myusername" # The user you want ot run the script as

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting Myscript: "
        #Your command follows:
        su - $OWNER -c "/usr/local/bin/myscript"
        #or possibly:
        su - $OWNER -c "screen -d -m -S myscript /usr/local/bin/myscript"
        echo $? > /var/lock/myscript
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    stop)
        echo -n "Shutdown Myscript: "
        kill $(cat /var/lock/myscript)
        rm -f /var/lock/myscript
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    reload|restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;  
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop|restart|reload"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

and save it as `/etc/init.d/myscript`.

2: Run as root: `chkconfig --add myscript`

3: Run as root: `sudo ntsysv`

You can then reboot or run `service myscript start` to start it. If you chose to run it through `screen`, you can get access to the program with `screen -r myscript`.

Note that I haven't tested this since I use Gentoo which has a different init system, so details and spelling might be off. Have fun!